# Parameters Stored as Sessions - Pros / Cons?

Tags: php, session, wordpress

Some background on my system:

I have 1 query with multiple pages. There are filtering parameters on the left of the page which `$_POST`s on submission. The posted parameters will change the query at the top of the page.

My problem is that I am dealing with WordPress and the pagination is absolute links. Each time a user goes to a new page, I lose my `$_POST` array and the query resets.

I found a solution to this problem by storing my `$_POST` filtering parameters as `$_SESSION` parameters to bring them across multiple pages and thus keeping my query from resetting. Is this a bad idea?

I've read this question and answer: [Results stored in a session - good idea?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175818/results-stored-in-a-session-good-idea) but I wasn't sure if it was the same situation as mine or differernt. In this question it seems he is storing entire database results into a session then cutting it up as he needs versus I'm still making database queries just using whatever was in the last session. I am also not using ajax to paginate as states above, I do lose my `$_POST` array.

Is this the same scenario as the question previous posted just a different flavor? Is use of `$_SESSION` acceptable?

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Comment: I frequently store objects in the session so that I can skip refetching the same data from the database. I don't see any problem of "abusing" the session object in any way it suits you if it doesn't lead to bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major drawbacks to doing it this way:

1. Your site will break for any user who has cookies disabled. While this is not a common configuration, it does happen sometimes.
2. Users who try to open multiple tabs on your site may find their navigation going haywire.

I tend to avoid it for these reasons, but if it is the only realistic way (I've never worked with wordpress so don't know what alternatives you have) then neither of these is a complete showstopper.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 1 query with multiple pages. There are filtering parameters on the left of the page which $_POSTs on submission.

That is your problem right there. A query should be a GET according to the HTTP verbs, and using a GET would make it easily possible to simply pass the search query along from page to page (this is how every single search engine does it).